# Can't install inkscape on Yosemite with homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

It seems like I should be able to install inkscape with something like

```
brew install inkscape
```

based on what I've seen online. Unfortunately, when I try this I get

```
Error: No available formula for inkscape 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

**Update 2017**:

The preferred method to install Inkscape with homebrew in 2017 is:

```
brew update
brew cask install xquartz
brew cask install inkscape
```

**Previous Answer**:

Inkscape is a cask that you need to tap first before installing.

I tried a few of the suggestions given on this page, and the only thing that worked for me is a [minor variation to **jherran's** answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192235/5472):

```
$ brew search inkscape
$ brew tap homebrew/gui
$ brew install inkscape
```

At that point, I got the response **`Installing inkscape from homebrew/homebrew-x11`** and the installation completed successfully. The result from the `brew search` command has changed a few times so be on the guard for it to change again and just tap the correct reply from the search command if it's not `homebrew/gui` next time you search.

Comment: While following these instructions today (with Homebrew 0.9.9 and OSX 10.10) the result of `brew search inkscape` was `homebrew/gui/inkscape`. Running `brew tap homebrew/gui` and `brew install inkscape` works as before.

Comment: @Pathogen You're right. I had to install Inkscape again a few weeks ago and my own answer no longer worked for me. I've been meaning to update it. I'll get to it soon. Thanks!

Comment: With the current homebrew version tapping is no longer needed for inkscape. `brew cask install inkscape` does the job (assuming you had previously installed `xquartz`)

Comment: `brew cask install inkscape` installs a distinct package from `brew install inkscape` See my answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/234223/106609

Answer (score 3):

Had the pleasure of attempting this on a fresh install of El Capitan this morning. I wanted both the GUI and command line interface. Unfortunately, it seems that the sanest solution was to install two versions, one from brew (for CLI) and the other from brew-cask (for GUI).

```
$ brew search inkscape
homebrew/gui/inkscape
Caskroom/cask/inkscape

$ brew cask install xquartz # required for GUI

$ brew cask install inkscape # for GUI

$ brew install homebrew/gui/inkscape # for CLI (yep)
==> Installing inkscape from homebrew/gui
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-gui/
==> Pouring inkscape-0.91_3.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/inkscape
Target /usr/local/bin/inkscape
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/inkscape'
To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite inkscape

$ brew link --overwrite inkscape # to get the CLI inkscape on your path rather than the brew-cask GUI
```

The problem with using the Cask version of Inkscape is that it doesn't handle relative paths very nicely, and apparently using it as a CLI [isn't recommended](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1449251/comments/1). But I was unable to get the vanilla Homebrew version of Inkscape working as a GUI.

Comment: Well done - chasing which cask and dependency is needed has changed quite a lot over the years for this package. Thanks for the great update.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
$ brew search inkscape
homebrew/x11/inkscape
$ brew tap homebrew/x11/inkscape
$ brew install inkscape
```

Comment: I get `homebrew/x11/inkscape   Caskroom/cask/inkscape` from `brew search inkscape`, but when I try `brew tap` for both `homebrew/x11/inkscape` and `Caskroom/cask/inkscape` I get `Error: Invalid tap name`

Comment: If you have brew cask, you can install it by typing `brew install Caskroom/cask/inkscape`.

Comment: ok, I installed homebrew cask, this seemed to make the installation work. Unfortunately inkscape still doesn't work from the command line (tells me `failed to load the requested file`) which makes it worthless to me. For some reason `brew uninstall inkscape` also doesn't work...

Comment: Try this: `brew uninstall Caskroom/cask/inkscape`

Comment: The "tap" command didn't work for me. I instead did `brew install hombrew/x11/inkscape` and that worked great. Might be something for the new version

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on Sierra (10.12.1) in December 2016.

```
brew update
brew cask install xquartz
brew cask install inkscape
```

Reboot machine.

Launch Inkscape from Applications directory. Wait a minute for the font cache to be built.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on 10.10.4 with brew:

```
brew update
brew install homebrew/x11/inkscape
```

I actually didn't need to run `brew tap homebrew/x11`.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Sierra 2017.

```
brew update
brew cask install xquartz
```

Restart your machine.

```
brew cask install inkscape
```

Answer (score 0):

As authors in the [official website](https://inkscape.org/en/download/mac-os/) says for Homebrew:

> If you've previously installed inkscape you should clean it before next installation:
>
> ```
> brew uninstall inkscape
> brew cleanup
> ```

**Installation:**

```
brew install caskformula/caskformula/inkscape
```

Comment: `brew install caskformula/caskformula/inkscape` would be for version 0.92.1 which does not (yet) have a dmg distribution.   while `brew cask install xquartz`, `brew cask install inkscape` would be an alternative to dmg for a 0.91 stable install. hence, "cask" vs. "caskformula".

Answer (score -1):

I have installed it successfully with the following command line:

```
brew install caskformula/caskformula/inkscape
```